# Is it correct to tell a professor that solutions to exercise sheets are online?

Tags: professorship, academic-life, tutoring

I'm a MSc student (second year) in  a math department in Europe and I have to check and correct the  exercise sheets of the students of the first year of Master degree attending a course this semester. Those points can add up to **+2** extra points in the final mark.
These exercise are taken from the course of the last year, which was given by another teacher.

Unfortunately, in the e-learning platform of the past year all the solutions by the previous teacher are still available and anyone can access it.

I think I should tell this to the teacher, but I'm afraid to be inappropriate, as I'm a student like them.

Best regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reckon most professors know that the solutions are available online. Nevertheless, telling them is a nice thing to do. It's a way of showing, that **you** care about the quality of the lecture, and it might even trigger a fruitful discussion.

I am well aware that the solutions to my problem sheets are available online. Students told me so, but it is also obvious from the number of correct and wrong solutions. How do I know this?

1. I use a random number generator to obtain different starting values for the problem sheets. Students, who don't pay attention, might get it wrong.
2. Whenever I add a new problem this particular question gets the least correct answers.

Now, filtering the scores from old problem sheets according to the two criteria above and correlating them with the scores of the final exam, it gets pretty obvious that "doing the homework" and "coming to "consultation hours" significantly influences the final grade. I show this data every semester, at the beginning of a new course. During this presentation I also mention that the solutions are online, however, I try to put this into the context it deserves: Trying to cheat on the problem sheets is a waste of time. The time is better spent, having a beer and discussing the subject with your fellow students.

Comment: I feel like this is excellent information should be reshaped to answer the question. Can I suggest that you put your last paragraph first--basically, **yes you should tell the professor**--, and then follow up with paragraphs 1 & 2 on why an instructor might not worry about the fact that the answers are already online, or how they might deal with it constructively?

Comment: @LeeHachadoorian: Your right, that's much better. Thank you.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that those exercises has been created by himself. Anyway, thanks for the answer, and of course, it has to be the student to put all the effort to understand as much as he can. (I'm still a student and I strongly believe so)

Answer (score 2):

Just send the prof an email or tell them in passing.

It's not your fault but they either know already or will be pleased to know so they can evaluate what they do.

What they do is either nothing or they may update the exercise material - students who want to progress will do the work anyway...